# Listen to JFrame resize events as the user drags their mouse?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouse

When a user clicks on the corner of a JFrame to resize and drags the mouse around, the JFrame redraws based on the current position of the mouse as the user drags. How can you listen to these events?

Below is the what I have currently tried:

```
public final class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    public TestFrame() {
        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                // This is only called when the user releases the mouse button.
                System.out.println("componentResized");
            }
        });
    }

    // These methods do not appear to be called at all when a JFrame
    // is being resized.
    @Override
    public void setSize(int width, int height) {
        System.out.println("setSize");
    }

    @Override
    public void setBounds(Rectangle r) {
        System.out.println("setBounds A");
    }

    @Override
    public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        System.out.println("setBounds B");
    }
}
```

How can I determine and constrain how the user resizes a window (based on the current aspect ratio of the window) as they are dragging around the mouse around?

Comment: @finnw can you please to clarify reason for your Bounty, because I see difference betweens `Java_1.4` and `Java_1.5`, but I can't found diference for `Java_6`, `note` but without deepest checking into `Nested` and `Inherits Method`

Comment: @mKorbel, I tried both methods (ComponentListener on JPanel; Override validate.) The code compiles and runs under both versions of Java but in Java 1.6 the layout is recalculated continuously, but in Java 1.5 only when I release the mouse.

Comment: @finnw are you resize JComponent or JFrame

Comment: @mKorbel, I am resizing the JFrame with the mouse, and as it has a `BorderLayout` the component (with `BorderLayout.CENTER`) should follow.

Comment: ComponentResizer by @camickr http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/ would be from Java5 age,

Comment: @finnw just idea are you tried to delay events from componentResized(ComponentEvent e) by using javax.swing.Timer, notice until resize ends you have to Timer#restart(), because you never know if resize ends, if resize ends then fire Action from Timer

Comment: @mKorbel: are you confusing this question with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738664/componentresized-event-for-component-in-java-but-only-execute-when-mouse-release ? It is the exact opposite problem.  I *want* componentResized to be called continuously, but it is not.

Comment: @finnw I think that this confuse way is safiest (MsOffice, Multimedia Player waiting ...Mozilla for example doesn't, that have problems with Antialiasing and Rendering for Fonts, Circle and Lines during resize)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need to override something like `validate` (don't forget to call the super). Of course, that still may not work if you are using a windowing system to configured to drag outlines.

Comment: How would I call the super for this? I thought you could only call super in a constructor?

Answer (score 59):

You can add a component listener and implement the componentResized function like that:

```
JFrame component = new JFrame("My Frame");

component.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() 
{  
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
            Component c = (Component)evt.getSource();
            //........
        }
});
```

**EDIT:** Apparently, for JFrame, the componentResized event is hooked to the mouseReleased event. That's why the method is invoked when the mouse button is released.

One way to achieve what you want, is to add a JPanel that will cover the whole area of your JFrame. Then add the componentListener to the JPanel (componentResized for JPanel is called even while your mouse is still dragging). When your frame is resized, your panel will also be resized too.

I know, this isn't the most elegant solution, but it works!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. However, componentResized only appears to be called when the user releases the mouse button. Is it possible to listen to resize events *as* the user is dragging the mouse?

Comment: @Clinton True! Sorry about that, I didn't read your question thoroughly!

Comment: @Clinton I was curious of how can this be done, and the only way I found was to add a JPanel in the JFrame. I don't know if this helps you. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your revised solution. I gave it a try and it worked well. However, in my case the validate option came out a little cleaner.

Comment: +1 cause I wouldn't have to override the function in a seperate class! :) This answer is helping even after 5 years.

Comment: ERROR: the second line should go: component.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() { @Override
  public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
   // TODO some action
  }}

Answer (score 9):

Another workaround (which is very similar to Alex's but a little more straightforward) is to listen to the events from the `JFrame`'s root pane instead:

```
public final class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    public TestFrame() {
        this.getRootPane().addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                // This is only called when the user releases the mouse button.
                System.out.println("componentResized");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Depending on other implementation details, it's possible that the root pane might be changed. If that's a possibility then you could override `setRootPane()` and deal with that. Since `setRootPane()` is protected and only called from the constructor though, it's unlikely you'll need to do that.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public void TestFrame() {`...?

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin, no, that's a constructor declaration, and constructors don't specify return types such as `void`.

Comment: "// This is only called when the user releases the mouse button."  -- it appears that it isn't merely when the mouse button is released.  When I use this code, it is called incessantly, which would support a dynamic resize; any way to resize once upon release of the mouse?

Comment: copy @MAXdB: any way to resize once upon release of the mouse?

Answer (score -2):

```
public class MouseDrag extends Component implements MouseListener,
    MouseMotionListener {
  /** The Image we are to paint */
  Image curImage;

  /** Kludge for showStatus */
  static Label status;

  /** true if we are in drag */
  boolean inDrag = false;

  /** starting location of a drag */
  int startX = -1, startY = -1;

  /** current location of a drag */
  int curX = -1, curY = -1;

  // "main" method
  public static void main(String[] av) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Mouse Dragger");
    Container cp = f.getContentPane();

    if (av.length < 1) {
      System.err.println("Usage: MouseDrag imagefile");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Image im = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(av[0]);

    // create a MouseDrag object
    MouseDrag j = new MouseDrag(im);

    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    cp.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new Label(
        "Hello, and welcome to the world of Java"));
    cp.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, j);
    cp.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, status = new Label());
    status.setSize(f.getSize().width, status.getSize().height);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  // "Constructor" - creates the object
  public MouseDrag(Image i) {
    super();
    curImage = i;
    setSize(300, 200);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
  }

  public void showStatus(String s) {
    status.setText(s);
  }

  // Five methods from MouseListener:
  /** Called when the mouse has been clicked on a component. */
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  /** Called when the mouse enters a component. */
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  /** Called when the mouse exits a component. */
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
  }


  // And two methods from MouseMotionListener:
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    Point p = e.getPoint();
    // System.err.println("mouse drag to " + p);
    showStatus("mouse Dragged to " + p);
    curX = p.x;
    curY = p.y;
    if (inDrag) {
      repaint();
    }
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int w = curX - startX, h = curY - startY;
    Dimension d = getSize();
    g.drawImage(curImage, 0, 0, d.width, d.height, this);
    if (startX < 0 || startY < 0)
      return;
    System.err.println("paint:drawRect @[" + startX + "," + startY
        + "] size " + w + "x" + h);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(startX, startY, w, h);
  }

}
```

Comment: -1.  This is basically a duplicate of the code in the question (which we already know does not solve the problem.)