# componentResized event for Component in Java, but only execute when mouse released

Tags: java, events, resize, components, listener

I need to do some calculations when one of my Components (a Canvas) gets resized. Unfortunately the calculations can take a few hundred milliseconds which causes the resize to lag heavily while being done. I'd like to solve that by only doing the calculation when the resizing ended (I guess when the mouse button gets released). How can I achieve that? So far I only have the following:

```
MyComponent.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        super.componentResized(e);
        // some calculation
    }       
});
```

Thanks.

PS: I know that for a JFrame the resized event gets fired only after the mouse button is released, but unfortunately I cannot put my Component into a JFrame or having it extend a JFrame.

Comment: Why are you using `AWT` components? Also, are the calculations relevant to the component undergoing the re-size event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

then you can start javax.swing.Timer with some delay and on resize only restart Timer
and by invoking Action or AbstractAction you can calculete anything and output to the
GUI will be on EDT

Comment: +1, The Timer is the way to go. The invokeLater() doesn't help.

Comment: There is no need to use invokeLater() when using a Timer. Also, the benefit of using a Timer is to just keep using timer.restart() every time a component resize event is generated. Using a Thread in combination with invokeLater() is a different solution that requires more coding since you need to support the restart() logic and should not be suggested in this reply. It will only confuse the poster. If you think it is a good solution then you should post a separate response.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag in `componentResized()` and have a `MouseListener` do the actual work.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a MouseListener like this:

```
public class MouseHandler implements MouseListener
{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(!running)
        {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
            running = true;
        }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        running = false;
        thread = null
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}

    public void run()
    {
        while(running)
        {
            try
            {
                //repaint the component or move it or somthing.
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                // repaint delay
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }

    Thread thread;
    boolean running;
}
```

You could throw in a MouseMotionListener if you want to change the location of the component