# Real-time listening to JFrame height and width

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe, mouselistener

I've got a situation where I would like to be able to know a JFrame's height and width as the user drags their mouse to resize the frame.

I researched this, and the answers provided at the following question helped me a tiny bit, but not all the way: [Listen to JFrame resize events as the user drags their mouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106367/listen-to-jframe-resize-events-as-the-user-drags-their-mouse)

My problem is: I have made my "HSFrame" class extend JFrame and implement ActionListener, MouseMotionListener (ActionListener is irrelevant to this question, however). What this question pertains to is MouseMotionListener.

I have a separate class called "CanvasPanel" that extends JPanel--this is where I use a graphics object to update real-time information by drawing strings.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    validate();
    canvas.repaint();
}
```

This is a code excerpt from my "HSFrame" class (extends JFrame, implements MouseMotionListener). In this code example, "canvas" is a CanvasPanel object, and I am calling its repaint() method whenever MouseDragged is called.

I chose to use a MouseMotionListener because this (supposedly) would give me real-time updates as opposed to ComponentListener's componentResized() method (which is tied to MouseReleased).

Everything updates 100% perfectly when I resize the frame from the top-left corner. The height, width, X, and Y values all repaint perfectly.

But it does not update in real-time when I resize from the bottom-right corner. And I don't know about you, but I prefer to resize things from the bottom-right.

In the "CanvasPanel" class itself, I extended ComponentListener and added a listener to an "HSFrame" object there--it does not update in real-time, which was fine, but it does repaint the height and width after the mouse is released, regardless of which corner the HSFrame was resized with.

Main question:
Is it possible to get the MouseMostionListener to know that I am resizing the JFrame from the bottom-right? It hears when I move the frame around by clicking and dragging the title bar, and it hears when I resize from the top-left corner (which is also interacting with the title bar). It just doesn't hear when anything goes on to the other borders of the JFrame.

Comment: Mmmm won't it fire a property change event?

Comment: The componentResized() event fires dynamically for me when resizing from the bottom/right I'm using JDK6_7 on XP. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://pastebin.com/Q0nbQcpm)
Here's as basic of an example as I can make.

Save that as MainClass.java, compile, and run. It should work like that as one JAVA file.

The issue here is as follows: Resizing the main application window doesn't repaint in real time as the user drags from the bottom right. It does repaint in real time dragging the from the top left.

This is what gets me though: if you drag the debug window from anywhere, it updates in real time.

So why won't the main window do that? I have added both listeners to both frames.

Bottom-right is the ONLY thing not working.

Comment: Sorry, here's a small fix to that example: [SSCCE](http://pastebin.com/NMWvxj6Y). I forgot to add canvas.repaint() to the ComponentListener methods in the ResizeFrame class..previously I just called repaint().

Comment: I would guess the SSCCE is only 15-20 lines so the code should be posted in the forum so we can all see it.

Comment: No, it's three classes.. The component listener code is 15-20 lines in itself

Comment: No, the SSCCE will be 15 lines of code. The point of a SSCCE is to simplify the probloem. Prove that it works with simple code and then implement the solution in your real program.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, but it is not possible to get an example of this problem down to 20 lines of code. If you want to help me any further, then the simplest example I can provide is there on the pastebin link. Have a look at the source, I commented throughout the entire thing.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do this with the mouse! Do it the easy way:
Write a [component listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html). Have HSFrame implement [`ComponentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) and put your resize code in `public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)`.

I think that the mouseListener won't work because when you're dragging from the bottom right your mouse is not in the `JFrame`, so the event listener doesn't pick it up.

Comment: Thanks, but I did indeed try this. Here's an [SSCCE](http://pastebin.com/Q0nbQcpm) showing what I'm talking about (save the raw code as MainClass.java, compile, then run it). The ONLY thing that does NOT update real-time is resizing the "ResizeFrame" (equivalent to HSFrame from the example) from the bottom right. I just don't get it--even resizing the debug frame from the bottom-right works. I have added both ComponentListener and MouseMotionListener to both frames, yet the bottom-right of the ResizeFrame does not repaint as the mouse is dragged.

Comment: Sorry, here's a small fix to that example: [SSCCE](http://pastebin.com/NMWvxj6Y). I forgot to add canvas.repaint() to the ComponentListener methods in the ResizeFrame class..previously I just called repaint().

Comment: I decided to just live with the problem for now, as I am only making the thing update debug information, which has nothing really to do with the actual program (height/width stuff for best placement of components and things like that). But if anyone can still figure out if it's possible to do what I wanted originally, that would be great