# Smaller down the image size in JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

I trying to create a GUI as image below

[image]

However, when I run my file, the size of the image still remain the original size

[image]

How can I reduce the size of the image so I can add text beside ?

```
public class HomePage extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new HomePage();
  }

  public HomePage() throws IOException {
    this.setTitle("Picture Application");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);
    BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\seng\\Desktop\\logo.png"));
    myPicture.getScaledInstance(10,30,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
    add(picLabel);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: From what I can tell, this is the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343098/resize-a-picture-to-fit-a-jlabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myPicture.getScaledInstance(10,30,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

The above statement returns a new BufferedImage which you never reference.

The code should be:

```
//myPicture.getScaledInstance(10,30,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);    
Image scaled = myPicture.getScaledInstance(10,30,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(scaled));
```

Comment: `cannot convert from Image to BufferedImage`

Comment: @Seng, Ok, I had a typo. Any code we post here is not tested. Did you not understand the basic concept that you need to assign the scaled image to a variable in order to use it? Just change the statement to use an `Image` variable. Take the time to read the API when you are given a suggestion in the forum.