# Creating a JTable with a links on the right side

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm working on a project for work where I input a log file, parse it based on the
threads in the log and place the complete thread confirmation in an JTable. For each thread if there is an error or okay message in a specific column it shows up as either red or blue. I have already implemented this. The next step in my project is to implement a bar on the right side of the GUI that will show up links that you can click and it will go to that row of the JTable.

A good example of this would be in the NetBeans IDE. When you are looking at the 
the main window and you select any variable, there is a bar on the right that shows the 
occurrences of that variable. This is an idea what I need to implement.

EDIT:
This is a newer version that I'm working on with a sample from the tutorials. What I did was create 3 "element" panes (Each with their own layout managers of course) and then added them to a border layout manager. This part works fine. The issue I'm having is wether or not I can have the JTable on the side change the row heights as the size of the gui changes (full screen, or made smaller).

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package testcolumnheadings;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import testcolumnheadings.TestColumnHeadings.Status;
import static testcolumnheadings.TestColumnHeadings.table;

public class TestColumnHeadings extends JPanel {

    enum Status {SELECTED, DESELECTED, INDETERMINATE}
    DefaultTableModel model = null;
    static JTable table = null;
    static JTable jbl = null;
    static JFileChooser fileChooser;
    static File prtFile = null;
    static String prtFilePath = null;

    public TestColumnHeadings(){
        super (new BorderLayout());
        Object[] columnNames = {Status.INDETERMINATE, "Integer", "String"};
        Object[][] data = {{true, 1, "BBB"}, {false, 12, "AAA"}, 
            {true, 2, "DDD"}, {false, 5, "CCC"},
            {true, 3, "EEE"}, {false, 6, "GGG"},
            {true, 4, "FFF"}, {false, 7, "HHH"},
            {true, 1, "III"}, {false, 312, "JJJ"}, 
            {true, 12, "KKK"}, {false, 75, "LLL"},
            {true, 2, "DDD"}, {false, 5, "CCC"},
            {true, 3, "EEE"}, {false, 6, "GGG"},
            {true, 4, "FFF"}, {false, 7, "HHH"},
            {true, 1, "III"}, {false, 312, "JJJ"}, 
            {true, 12, "KKK"}, {false, 75, "LLL"},
            {true, 2, "DDD"}, {false, 5, "CCC"},
            {true, 3, "EEE"}, {false, 6, "GGG"},
            {true, 4, "FFF"}, {false, 7, "HHH"},
            {true, 1, "III"}, {false, 312, "JJJ"}, 
            {true, 12, "KKK"}, {false, 75, "LLL"},
            {true, 13, "MMM"}, {false, 46, "NNN"},
            {true, 14, "OOO"}, {true, 67, "PPP"},
            {true, 11, "QQQ"}, {false, 112, "RRR"}, 
            {true, 22, "SSS"}, {false, 35, "TTT"},
            {true, 23, "UUU"}, {false, 56, "VVV"},
            {true, 24, "WWW"}, {true, 97, "XXX"}};
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames){
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column){
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };

        table = new JTable(model){           
            @Override
            public void updateUI(){
                super.updateUI();

                TableCellRenderer r = getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class);
                if(r instanceof JComponent){
                    ((JComponent)r).updateUI();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public Component prepareEditor (TableCellEditor editor, int row, int column){
                Component c = super.prepareEditor(editor, row, column);
                if (c instanceof JCheckBox){
                    JCheckBox b = (JCheckBox)c;
                    b.setBackground(getSelectionBackground());
                    b.setBorderPainted(true);
                }
                return c;
            }
        };

        int modelColumnIndex = 0;
        TableCellRenderer renderer = new HeaderRenderer (table.getTableHeader(), modelColumnIndex);

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(modelColumnIndex).setHeaderRenderer(renderer);

        model.addTableModelListener(new HeaderCheckBoxHandler(table, modelColumnIndex));

        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(320, 240));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Table Header Check Box");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        TestColumnHeadings tstHead = new TestColumnHeadings();

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p1.add(tstHead);

        jbl = new JTable(table.getRowCount(), 1);
        jbl.setRowHeight(6);
        jbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(6);
//        jbl.;

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p2.add(jbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Save Selection");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                int i, j;
                boolean row;
                String selected = null;
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel();

                for (i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i ++){

                    row = (boolean)table.getValueAt(i, 0);
                    if (row){
                        if (selected == null){
                            selected = (String)(i + " " + table.getValueAt(i, 1) + " " + table.getValueAt(i, 2) + "\n");
                        }
                        else{
                            selected += (String)(i + " " + table.getValueAt(i, 1) + " " + table.getValueAt(i, 2) + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
                fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
                j = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(new JFileChooser());

                if (j == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    prtFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    prtFilePath = prtFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    System.out.println("Save File Selected: " + prtFilePath);
                    try {
                        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(prtFile)) {
                            fw.write(selected);
                        }
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JOptionPane(), "File saved completed.");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(TestColumnHeadings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        p3.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(p3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public class StatusColumnCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
            JLabel l = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            l.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            l.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

            if (table.getValueAt(0, row).equals(true)){
                l.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                l.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            else {
                l.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                l.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            }
            return l;
        }
    }
}

class HeaderRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {
    private final JLabel label = new JLabel ("Check All");
    private int targetColumnIndex;

    public HeaderRenderer (JTableHeader header, int index){
        super ((String)null);
        this.targetColumnIndex = index;
        setOpaque(false);
        setFont(header.getFont());
        header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e){
                JTableHeader header = (JTableHeader)e.getSource();
                JTable table = header.getTable();
                TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
                int vci = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
                int mci = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(vci);
                if (mci == targetColumnIndex){
                    TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn(vci);
                    Object v = column.getHeaderValue();
                    boolean b = Status.DESELECTED.equals(v);
                    TableModel m = table.getModel();
                    column.setHeaderValue(b ? Status.SELECTED : Status.DESELECTED);
                    for (int i = 0; i < m.getRowCount(); i++){
                            table.setValueAt(b, i, 0);
                    }
                    header.repaint();                    
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable tbl, Object val, boolean isS, boolean hasF, int row, int col){
        TableCellRenderer r = tbl.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        JLabel l = (JLabel)r.getTableCellRendererComponent(tbl, val, isS, hasF, col, col);
        if (targetColumnIndex == tbl.convertColumnIndexToModel(col)){
            if (val instanceof Status){
                switch ((Status) val){
                    case SELECTED:
                        setSelected(true);
                        setEnabled(true);
                        break;
                    case DESELECTED:
                        setSelected(false);
                        setEnabled(true);
                        break;
                    case INDETERMINATE:
                        setSelected(true);
                        setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                }
            }else{
                setSelected(true);
                setEnabled(false);
            }
            label.setIcon(new ComponentIcon(this));
            l.setIcon(new ComponentIcon(label));
            l.setText(null);
        }

        return l;
    }
    @Override
    public void updateUI(){
        setText(null); 
        super.updateUI();
    }
}

class HeaderCheckBoxHandler implements TableModelListener {
    private final JTable table;
    private final int targetColumnIndex;

    public HeaderCheckBoxHandler (JTable table, int index){
        this.table = table;
        this.targetColumnIndex = index;
    }
    @Override
    public void tableChanged (TableModelEvent e){
        if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE && e.getColumn() == targetColumnIndex){
            int vci = table.convertColumnIndexToView(targetColumnIndex);
            TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vci);
            if (!Status.INDETERMINATE.equals(column.getHeaderValue())){
                column.setHeaderValue(Status.INDETERMINATE);
            } else{
                boolean selected = true, deselected = true;
                TableModel m = table.getModel();
                for (int i = 0; i < m.getRowCount(); i ++){
                    Boolean b = (Boolean)m.getValueAt(i, targetColumnIndex);
                    selected &= b;
                    deselected &= !b;
                    if (selected == deselected)
                        return;
                }
                if (selected){
                    column.setHeaderValue(Status.SELECTED);

                }else if (deselected){
                    column.setHeaderValue(Status.DESELECTED);
                }else{
                    return;
                }
            }
            JTableHeader h = table.getTableHeader();
            h.repaint(h.getHeaderRect(vci));
        }
    }
}

class ComponentIcon implements Icon {
    private final JComponent cmp;

    public ComponentIcon(JComponent cmp){
        this.cmp = cmp;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth(){
        return cmp.getPreferredSize().width;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight(){
        return cmp.getPreferredSize().height;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y){
        SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, cmp, (Container)c, x, y, getIconWidth(), getIconHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code or image, do you try to do it?

Comment: Here is a pic of a sample of the GUI that I have already created. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lfqf2g8so5vxd9e/LogPic.png As I said I need to try and create the bar on the right of the GUI, hopefully on the right of the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need somthing like this

[image]

At left you have your table, and at the right you have Panel with information. I use `BorderLayout` for that, read [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). In the riht panel you can write your logic for links which would be call `t.editCellAt(a)` or somthing else. And code:

```
public class Form extends JFrame {

    public Form() {
        DefaultTableModel model;
        final JTable t = new JTable(model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{},new Object[]{1,2,3,4,5}));
        for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
            model.addRow(new Object[]{i,i,i,i,i});
        }
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(t);
        final RightPanel right = new RightPanel();
        t.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
                right.col.setText("Col " + t.getSelectedColumn());
                right.row.setText("Row " + t.getSelectedRow());
                if(t.getSelectedColumn() != -1 && t.getSelectedRow() != -1){
                    right.text.setText("Value " + t.getValueAt(t.getSelectedRow(),t.getSelectedColumn()));
                }
            }
        });
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Form().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class RightPanel extends JPanel{

        JLabel row;
        JLabel col;
        JLabel text;

        public RightPanel(){
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            JLabel l = new JLabel("Option Panel");
            c.gridy = 0;
            add(l,c);
            row = new JLabel("2");
            c.gridy++;
            add(row,c);
            col = new JLabel("3");
            c.gridy++;
            add(col,c);
            text = new JLabel("4");
            c.gridy++;
            add(text,c);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex2410 for the quick response. I will try to implement the code in my project and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106367/listen-to-jframe-resize-events-as-the-user-drags-their-mouse I found an answer to one of my issues. To resize the row heights for the link table I added an action listener to the frame itself.