# How do you check to see if a window has been resized?

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I would like the text size of a button to increase as the window's height is resized.

```
button.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, frame.getHeight() / 20));
```

However, I cannot find anywhere to put this in my code so that the font size will update in real time. What would I add?

Comment: You could try something like the solution suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2106381/3284624

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to have your `JFrame` implement 'ComponentListener`. One of the methods in this interface is :

```
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    // Perform calculation here
}
```

Another option is to override `JFrame` `paintComponent` method to recalculate size with each paint:

```
Dimension size;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
  if (!size.equals(getSize()){
    size = getSize();      
  }
}
```