# How to scale an image when resizing the program's screen?

Tags: java, image

I'm creating an image editor. I have scaled the loaded images to the right size. But the images are of fixed size and don't resize after the initial loading. I need the images to scale whenever the screen size has changed. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106367/listen-to-jframe-resize-events-as-the-user-drags-their-mouse) might help you. resize the image inside a listener that listens to resize events.

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using?

Comment: Please respect grammar. Capitalize the beginning of a sentence and use punctuation. This will make your questions more comfortable to read and easier to understand. Consider to use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/), if English is not your native language.

Comment: You need javascript to listen for screen resize event. when the screen resizes event triggered catch width and height of your current browser and apply image size accordingly.

Comment: @BionicCode Ok, Thank you.

Comment: @swpalmer Swing

Comment: @Ammar Thank you, It worked.